Insomnia - Collection variables in version 9.3.3
I'm using Insomnia and I use a lot collection variables. When I access the collection I could see a gear where I click to edit my variables.
Now, in the current version the gear icon is gone and I cannot find where I can edit the collection variables. I searched in the documentation and other pages but I didn't find anything related.
How can I access and edit the collection variables now?
I open a collection and search in Insomnia UI where I could edit the variables but I didn't find it. I try to search in Insomnia documentation but didn't find it either.

Well, I found the answer.
Now, it is necessary to click on "base environment" and then in the pencil icon to edit the collection variables.

